# Java Slick2D: Is it possible to turn a slick Image into a bufferedImage

Tags: java, image, slick2d

Is it possible to turn a slick2D image back into a buffered image?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and cite which [Slick2D API](http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/) you are using.

Comment: Try [`org.newdawn.slick.imageout.ImageIOWriter#saveImage()`](http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/imageout/ImageIOWriter.html).